# JavaScript updating an array element with index

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I currently have an `arrayList()` called `players` in JavaScript in which I `push` data into it using: `players.push({name: msg.name, map: msg.map, coords: msg.coords});`

Here is an example data: `{ name: 'weka', map: '5', coords: '12.4' }` for example `players[0]`.

Here is what I am doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; ++i) {
  if (msg.name === players[i].name) {
    console.log("Updating  index ("+i+") player: " + msg.name);
    //players[i].push({name: msg.name, map: msg.map, coords: msg.coords});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
players[i].push({name: msg.name, map: msg.map, coords: msg.coords});
```

should be

```
players[i] = {name: msg.name, map: msg.map, coords: msg.coords});
```

You haven't defined `players[i]` to be an Array, so there's nothing to "push" to. And I asume that you wish to change existing value and not insert an extra depth.

Comment: Also, if your key names are the same you can just do `players[i] = msg`

Comment: @adam That inserts a reference to `msg` inside `players`. Copying the fields over one by one creates an independent new object.

Answer (score 2):

`players.push({name: msg.name, map: msg.map, coords: msg.coords});` is OK,

What you did is `players[i].push({name: msg.name, map: msg.map, coords: msg.coords});`, 
`players[i]` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

players[i] - is object (`{ name: 'weka', map: '5', coords: '12.4' } for example`), not array
If you want to set set props just use `palyers[i]['prop'] = 'prop';`